# Variations on the definition of "chain homotopy"

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

Suppose I have two chain complexes $(C_k, \partial_k^C)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq0}}$ and $(D_k, \partial_k^D)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq0}}$ of modules over a ring $R$, and a chain homotopy $(\gamma_k)_{k\in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}}$ between them. A chain homotopy between two maps $f, g: C_{\bullet} \to D_{\bullet}$ ensures that $f$ and $g$ induce the same maps on homology, because of the chain homotopy relation $\partial_{k+1}^D \circ \gamma_k + \gamma_{k-1} \circ \partial_k^C = f_k - g_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$.

But it seems that the relation $\partial_{k+1}^D \circ \gamma_k - \gamma_{k-1} \circ \partial_k^C = f_k - g_k$ would have the same effect, or even $r_k \cdot  \partial_{k+1}^D \circ \gamma_k + r_k' \cdot \gamma_{k-1} \circ \partial_k^C$ for $r_i \in R$, where $r_k$ is different for each $k$.

What can be learned from this ambiguity (assuming I am correct)?

Comment: You just change $\partial_k^C$ to $-\partial_k^C$

Comment: "What can be learned from this ambiguity": signs are a horrible affair in homological algebra. Alternatively, put a minus sign in front of every odd (or even, I'm not sure) $\gamma_k$ to see that you get the same notion.